# Add unique identifier to intercepted object Aspectj

Tags: android, aspectj

How to provide a unique identifier to an intercepted object instance from aspect class? We have defined a tracking interface that should provide a unique id for each intercepted object but when this it's run it throws a class cast exception as if the interface is not weaved in on an intercepted object.

This is the calling code

```
val urlConnection: HttpURLConnection
    val result: String?
    try {
        //Connect
        urlConnection = URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
        urlConnection.requestMethod = "POST"
        urlConnection.connectTimeout = 10000
        urlConnection.connect()

        //Write
        val outputStream = urlConnection.outputStream
        val writer = BufferedWriter(OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"))
        writer.write("data")
        writer.close()
        outputStream.close()
        val responseCode = urlConnection.responseCode
        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            //Read
            val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(urlConnection.inputStream, "UTF-8"))

            var line: String?
            val sb = StringBuilder()

            while (bufferedReader.readLine() != null) {
                line = bufferedReader.readLine()
                sb.append(line)
            }

            bufferedReader.close()
            result = sb.toString()

        } else {
            result = "response : $responseCode"
        }

        Log.e(this.javaClass.simpleName, result)

    } catch (e: UnsupportedEncodingException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: JSONException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: ProtocolException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: MalformedURLException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
```

This is the aspect class

```
@Pointcut("call(* java.net.URL.openConnection())")
public void getUrlOpenConnectionPointCut() {
}

@AfterReturning(pointcut = "getUrlOpenConnectionPointCut()", returning = "connection")
public void afterActivityCreated(JoinPoint joinPoint, HttpURLConnection connection) throws Exception {
   TrackInterface tracInt = (TrackInterface)connection;
    tracInt.setTrackId();
}

@DeclareMixin("java.net.HttpURLConnection")
public static TrackInterface addTrackingIdentifier() {
    return new TrackInterfaceImpl();
}

public interface TrackInterface {
    void setTrackId();

    int getTrackId();
}

static class TrackInterfaceImpl implements TrackInterface {

    int trackId;

    @Override
    public void setTrackId() {
        trackId = new Random(Integer.MAX_VALUE).nextInt();
    }

    @Override
    public int getTrackId() {
        return trackId;
    }
}
```